# CRM 2011 - View leads once a field has changed

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Any ideas or help would be appreciated on this issue.

I have a lead form that users fill out. A manager want to know every time 2 fields are changed or updated. For example we have 2 fields that telesales must fillout to qualify as a KPI.

I need to create a view that shows all leads a user has edited a particular field. Without creating workflows to populate a field when this particular field is edited does anyone have any idea how i can do this.

End result is a daily view that shows leads with these fields edited that day, not just lead forms edited.

thanks

Comment: why creating a workflow to fill a particular field is not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a view you can show leads that have been modified that day AND leads where some combination of the two fields have a range of values but you can't reliably combine the two i.e. leads where either/or those 2 fields have been modified today.

Options I can think of:

Create a hidden field that gets set with current date by custom JS OR plugin if the 2 field change condition is met. Then view can use the hidden field.

As Guido says, create a workflow that fires off an email to the manager when the 2 field condition is met, explain why this is an improvement because (s)he gets notified in real time (wow!) and quietly forget about the view.

Update: another option might be to intercept the retrievemultiple of the fetch with a plugin and do the necessary logic there, but...you still don't know for sure when the field(s) changed, just the entire record. There is a field audit capability built in to crm which I have never used but conceivably that could give you the necessary info on when the field(s) changed.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to avoid adding workflows as i'm already using quite a few for the lead entity.

Looks like the workflow option is the only way.

Thanks for everyones feedback. I wanted to check i wasn't missing some obvious answer and creating workflows for the sake of it.

cheers